# OpenCV Release build error: expected a type specifier

Tags: c++, opencv, stl

I'm getting some build error in my application (using OpenCV 3.0) when I compile it in **release** mode (MT runtime library, Visual Studio Express 2012 Update 5).
The build is fine in Debug mode (MTd).
The two builds link against the proper **static libraries** ("d" for debug, not for release) and the error happens before the linking stage, in the cvstd.hpp file.

This is a x64 build and WIN32 is defined (one of the libraries needs it).

Error in cvstd.hpp @ line 155: expected a type specifier

```
/*!
  The STL-compilant memory Allocator based on cv::fastMalloc() and cv::fastFree()
*/
template<typename _Tp> class Allocator
{
public:
    typedef _Tp value_type;
    typedef value_type* pointer;
    typedef const value_type* const_pointer;
    typedef value_type& reference;
    typedef const value_type& const_reference;
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    template<typename U> class rebind { typedef Allocator<U> other; };

    explicit Allocator() {}
    ~Allocator() {}
    explicit Allocator(Allocator const&) {}
    template<typename U>
    explicit Allocator(Allocator<U> const&) {}

    // address
    pointer address(reference r) { return &r; }
    const_pointer address(const_reference r) { return &r; }

    pointer allocate(size_type count, const void* =0) { return reinterpret_cast<pointer>(fastMalloc(count * sizeof (_Tp))); }
    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type) { fastFree(p); }

    void construct(pointer p, const _Tp& v) { new(static_cast<void*>(p)) _Tp(v); }
    void destroy(pointer p) { p->~_Tp(); }

    size_type max_size() const { return cv::max(static_cast<_Tp>(-1)/sizeof(_Tp), 1); }
};
```

The error is at the void construct(...) line. I have no idea if it's a bug, an incompatibility with VC2012 STL implementation, or what?

I tried the 2.4.9, with same results.

Anybody?

Thanks!

Comment: Visual studio 2012 is vc11... Are you sure you are linking correct libraries?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.
The error happens before the linking stage, when compiling this cvstd.hpp header.

Some STL incompatibilities have been reported for OpenCV, but I don't understand why this error only shows up in Release mode?